# Why is my logo not scaling/resizing html/css?

Tags: html, css, image, web

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.navbar,
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714128376884887644/783384657366482954/Double20Hospital20Doors20push20plate20and20kickplate.png" alt=""></a>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul2">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What I tried was directly scaling my logo with my class of logo but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my output:

[image]

(It's cut off, but the picture continues to show a door down the page).

Wondering how to make it so it does this:

[image]

Ignore the misalignment and spacing problems, that's just my quick screenshot recreation.

I also tried putting `display: in-line block` in my .logo{} but it doesn't do anything.

How can I rescale and position my logo to be in line with everything else?

Comment: you should resize the actual image and not use 1024x768 image when it's only displayed as 80x80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `img` is not being given a width or height. The `img` element doesn't care that the `logo` element has a width and height, it will scale to its native width/height, unless you tell it not to.

I set the img to have a width of `100%`, which means, "100% of its container". I set the height to `auto` so it doesn't distort.

That said, you should probably crop and resize the actual image to the largest it will ever be - so you're not loading a huge image for something small.

```
.logo img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.logo img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.navbar,
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714128376884887644/783384657366482954/Double20Hospital20Doors20push20plate20and20kickplate.png" alt=""></a>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul2">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: agree, however I would use height:100% to get what the OP wants

Comment: @Jnui why? OP is getting exactly what they want. A scaled image that works within the containing element. It makes no difference in this case, since the containing element is square.

Answer (score 1):

Place the class="logo" on the image element.

Example line to change:

```
<img class="logo" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714128376884887644/783384657366482954/Double20Hospital20Doors20push20plate20and20kickplate.png" alt=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the class on the img tag. `<img class="logo" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/714128376884887644/783384657366482954/Double20Hospital20Doors20push20plate20and20kickplate.png" alt=""></a>` also it is good practice to include text in the alt.